# Rails link_to assigning class and id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

```
<%= link_to event do  %>
  #bunch of stuff making up the partial.
<% end %>
```

So I'm trying to assign an ID and a class to each item in a partial.  I've seen where you have to call the full `link_to` function like `<%= link_to event, { controller: :controller, action: :action }, {class: 'someClass', id: 'someId' } %>`.

That's not working for me, because of the do block, methinks?  Ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
<%= link_to event, id: "an-id", class: "some-class" do  %>
  #bunch of stuff making up the partial.
<% end %>
```

Comment: That did it!  I feel like I tried that, but it didn't work.  No mind, it's all good!

Answer (score 6):

You can do

```
<%= link_to 'event', { controller: :pages, action: :home }, class: 'someClass', id: 'someId'  %>
```

which will give you

```
<a href="/the_generated_path" class="someClass" id="someId">event</a>
```

To make `'event'` actually an HTML div you can do

```
<%= link_to(raw("<div>..</div>"), ....)  %>
```

Comment: I liked this one better, succinct for the win